# Diferencias entre las formas de definir los valores que tendrá un arreglo

Tags: java, array

He notado que existen dos formas de definir un arreglo y sus valores que tendrá, pero no sé si haya alguna diferencia significativa a parte del obvio hecho de que la forma de hacerlo es distinta.

**Forma 1:**

```
int arreglo[]={1,2,3,4};
```

**Forma 2:**

```
int arreglo[]=new int[]{1,2,3,4};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En general son **equivalentes**, pero la Forma 1 solo se puede usar al definir la variable

**Forma 1**:

```java
int arreglo[]= {1,2,3,4}; // es válido
arreglo = {5,6,7}; // es un error de sintaxis
```

**Forma 2**:

```java
int arreglo[] = new int[] {1,2,3,5}; // es válido
arreglo = new int[] {5,6,7}; // también es válido
```

Answer (score 0):

En la **Forma 1**

```
int arreglo[]={1,2,3,4};
```

Estas creando el arreglo e inicializandolo al asignarle un valor.

En la **Forma 2**

```
int arreglo[]=new int[]{1,2,3,4};
```

Estas creando un arreglo de lado izquierdo del **=** y del lado derecho igual, solo que en el lado izquierdo no tiene valor aún y del lado derecho ya tiene valor pero no identificador (nombre). Por lo que estarás creando por así decirlo dos arreglos; uno con nombre y sin valor **int arreglo[]** y otro con valor pero sin nombre **new int[]{1,2,3,4}** cuando dejas el **=** (asignador) ahora le pasas ese contenido sin nombre al identificador **arreglo** que no tenía valor.